# chkdsk forever writing to the Bad Clusters File?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ntfs, chkdsk

I need some guidance with a mysterious behavior of the Windows 7's `chkdsk` on a 500 GB NTFS partition of a Seagate Barracuda 3 TB connected to a Samsung Story Station.

`chkdsk` seems to freeze towards the end of the process, beyond stage 5 (adding 67,036,670 bad clusters to the Bad Clusters File). The strange thing is the `chkdsk`'s status never says "not responding" in the Task Manager, so it's not frozen. At that stage, there's no progress of bad clusters count and no log writing until the process has finished, so I don't know how much it left.

[image]

I've tried three times to let it go all the way, and the last time it ran for around two days with the same outcome, so I have to close the console window.

Before, I tried with `SFC /scannow` and `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`, but as far as I get, those two commands only work with the first hard drive, not external drives.

[image]

[image]

What I want to fix with `chkdsk` is one corrupt inode, which doesn't let **TestDisk** run over that partition (which it did successfully over other NTFS partition in the same hard drive).

```
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0xa42ffb30  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 37503  usa_count: 38646: Invalid argument
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
ntfs_attr_find: Corrupt inode (-1): Input/output error
```

Answer (score 2):

If the disk has over 67 million bad clusters, the least of your worries is one corrupt inode. You'd best try to recover any valuable files off the disk, and replace it.